# Certified Ethical Hacking courses

Tags: network, penetration-test

I want to take a CEH exam, I'd like to know what tutorials and books are recomended for this kind of study.

I also would like to know if there are certifications that are better-recognized, so that I can focus on them.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You mention you want to WRITE an exam, yet it seems, you have no knowlege on the subject matter.

Comment: Writing an exam is a long term goal. Right now i just need tutorial material(videos and pdf )for the exam which i can go through.Have edited the question

Comment: Hi @OnaQuest, welcome to [security.se]. Please see the [FAQ] and also [ask] - your question is not a good fit for the SE format, since you're basically asking for a product recommendation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Materials for CEH**

The [at-home](http://iclass.eccouncil.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=141&Itemid=156) learning options from EC-Council itself were very good when I took it for v6.

Various study guides are available, but don't cover the full extent of the CEH material, so I won't even link to them here.

**Other Certifications**

CEH (I hold this cert) is an entry-level ethical hacking certification. It shows that you know what various hacking tools are and what they can do. It basically shows that you have 'heard of' ways to break into networks and servers [i.e. "What's Ettercap?"].

[Security+](http://certification.comptia.org/getcertified/certifications/security.aspx) is a more general security certification and covers more ground, but not ethical hacking.

But if you are looking for the 'cream' of ethical hacking certifications (in my opinion), look at the [OSCP](http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/). It is not as well-known as the CEH, but it requires you to actually hack servers, write exploits, and produce a penetration testing report. Plus it is aimed for those who may not know much before the class (if so, get the 90 day lab option and try everything out).

Practical experience is the best 'certification'. Being able to explain in a single sentence how you **HAVE** accomplished a task is worth more than papers. Fortunately, there are tons of materials to help you get that kind of experience. So, not matter which certification you go for, make sure you are spending time each week trying out a new tool or technique.

**Certifications in General**

I know that lots of people look down on certifications, but they are a valuable tool to get an employed position in the area you want to work in so that you can gain on-the-job experience while working with pros who do have the experience. You just have to be honest about what the certification is. It doesn't prove you can do anything, it simply shows you have a minimum body of knowledge. And that has some worth.

Comment: Thats a great answer. But one more thing i would like to know - are there any free video tutorials online where i can learn. Also what is the exact difference between the ceh v6 and ceh v7.

Comment: v7 has a practical component. Youtube has various ethical (and not so ethical) tutorials. But look at securitytube.net for high quality and targeted videos. They also have some low cost courses on a couple topics.